# save png file in application image folder without using savedialogfile

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight-4.0

I save a png file using savedialogfile. But I want to save it in application IMG folder. My code is as follows:

```
if (lastSnapshot != null)//writableBitmap object lastSnapshot
        {
            var dlg = new SaveFileDialog();
            dlg.DefaultExt = ".png";
            dlg.Filter = "PNG File|*.png";
            if (dlg.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                using (var pngStream = GetPngStream(lastSnapshot))//return Stream type 
                using (var file = dlg.OpenFile())
                {
                    byte[] binaryData = new Byte[pngStream.Length];
                    long bytesRead = pngStream.Read(binaryData, 0, (int)pngStream.Length);
                    file.Write(binaryData, 0, (int)pngStream.Length);
                    file.Flush();
                    file.Close();
                }
            }
        }
```

How to do it? I'll be grateful to anyone who will help me. Thanks in advance.

[Adjacent question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13603030/save-png-file-in-application-image-folder-in-silverlight)

Comment: You want to save it in a different location than what the user chooses? That is very counter intuitive... You shouldn't let the user choose the location at all.

Comment: Side note: no need to call `Flush` or `Close` (the same `Dispose` method eventually) inside `using` which automatically calls `Dispose`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (lastSnapshot != null)//writableBitmap object lastSnapshot
{
     using (var pngStream = GetPngStream(lastSnapshot))//return Stream type 
     using (var file = File.Create(Path.Combine("ImageFolder", "ImageName.png")))
     {
         byte[] binaryData = new Byte[pngStream.Length];
         long bytesRead = pngStream.Read(binaryData, 0, (int)pngStream.Length);
         file.Write(binaryData, 0, (int)pngStream.Length);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming ASP.net...

You need to use [HttpServerUtility.MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx) to compute location of the path on your server and potentially adjust permissions on that folder to allow IIS to write there.

```
var filePath = Server.MapPath("images\\myFile.png");
using (var file = File.Create(filePath))
{
  pngStream.Copy(file);
}
```