# save png file in application image folder in silverlight

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight-4.0

I save a png file using silverlight. But I want to save it in application IMG folder. My code is as follows:

```
if (lastSnapshot != null)
        {
            string ImageName = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() + DateTime.Now.Month.ToString() + DateTime.Now.Day.ToString() + DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString()
            + DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString() + DateTime.Now.Second.ToString() + DateTime.Now.Millisecond.ToString() + ".png"; 
            string filePath=System.IO.Path.Combine("~/Images/", "" + ImageName + "");  
            using (var pngStream = GetPngStream(lastSnapshot))
            using (var file = File.Create(filePath))
            {
                byte[] binaryData = new Byte[pngStream.Length];
                long bytesRead = pngStream.Read(binaryData, 0, (int)pngStream.Length);
                file.Write(binaryData, 0, (int)pngStream.Length);
                file.Flush();
                file.Close();
            }

        }
```

I want to do it in silverlight. Can I do it? Can I save file directly in application folder? How to do it? I'll be grateful to anyone who will help me. Thanks in advance.

[Adjacent question of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13599599/save-png-file-in-application-image-folder-without-using-savedialogfile)

Comment: I write the code in MainPage.xaml.cs

Comment: Silverlight is a client side technology, it runs at the client in the browser. What do you mean with application folder?

Comment: Can i save image in server side.I have an IMG folder in application directory.Can ajax helps in this aspect.

Comment: Yes, you can send the image data through some AJAX call and serialize it using some server side technology, like ASP.NET.

Comment: How to do it.Can u explain briefly.i m very new in this technology.

Comment: Maybe a start would be to read http://www.asp.net/web-api ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to provide a webservice or upload url at the server side and use that from within Silverlight at the client.

Silverlight applications to NOT have direct access the the server's folders because Silverlight executes at the client.